# Find time with millisecond using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to get time with millisecond
Currently using Timer() method but it just give access upto second 
Any idea?

Please make sure i don't want to convert second into millisecond want to get with millisecond

Answer (score 20):

In fact Timer function gives you seconds with milliseconds. Integer part of returned value is the number of seconds since midnight and the fraction part can be converted into milliseconds - just multiply it by 1000.

```
t = Timer

' Int() behaves exactly like Floor() function, i.e. it returns the biggest integer lower than function's argument
temp = Int(t)

Milliseconds = Int((t-temp) * 1000)

Seconds = temp mod 60
temp    = Int(temp/60)
Minutes = temp mod 60
Hours   = Int(temp/60)

WScript.Echo Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds

' Let's format it
strTime =           String(2 - Len(Hours), "0") & Hours & ":"
strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Minutes), "0") & Minutes & ":"
strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Seconds), "0") & Seconds & "."
strTime = strTime & String(4 - Len(Milliseconds), "0") & Milliseconds

WScript.Echo strTime
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses the standard dateserial in vbs

```
'get a timeserial with milliseconds
d1= date+ timer/86400
Wscript.echo datestamp(d1)&" "& timestamp(d1)

function datestamp(d)
  datestamp=year(d) &"/"& month(d) & "/" & day(d)
 end function

function timestamp(d)
  ymd=fix(d)
  h=hour(d)
  m=minute(d)
  s=second(d)
  timestamp=right("00" & h,2)&":"& right("00" & m,2)& ":" & right("00" & s,2)& ","& _
  right("000"& 86400000*(d-timeserial(h,m,s)-ymd),3)
end function
```

Answer (score -1):

Building upon MBu's answer, here's a Sub version. Sprinkle calls to this around your code for messages in the immediate window, so you can see where delays are happening.

```
' *** Debug.Print the time with milliseconds, and a message of your choice
Private Sub DebugPrintTime(strWhereFrom As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim sglTimer As Single
    Dim sglWholeSecs As Single
    Dim Millisecs As Variant  ' as a variant, Len() will give the length of string representation of this value
    Dim Seconds As Variant
    Dim Minutes As Variant
    Dim Hours As Variant
    Dim strTime As String

    sglTimer = timer
    sglWholeSecs = Int(sglTimer)
    Millisecs = Int((sglTimer - sglWholeSecs) * 1000)
    Seconds = sglWholeSecs Mod 60
    sglWholeSecs = Int(sglWholeSecs / 60)
    Minutes = sglWholeSecs Mod 60
    Hours = Int(sglWholeSecs / 60)

    strTime = String(2 - Len(Hours), "0") & Hours & ":"
    strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Minutes), "0") & Minutes & ":"
    strTime = strTime & String(2 - Len(Seconds), "0") & Seconds & "."
    strTime = strTime & String(3 - Len(Millisecs), "0") & Millisecs
    Debug.Print strTime, strWhereFrom

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error in Sub DebugPrintTime" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & strWhereFrom
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not VBScript.

Comment: Indeed, VB(6) rather.