# Format Time up to Milliseconds to use in log files

Tags: vbscript, milliseconds

My VBScript has a log file which logs information with current date and time using `FormatDateTime` Function.

I like to format time up to milliseconds and also in the following format:

```
MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss:mss AM/PM
```

But, unfortunately `FormatDateTime` doesn't let to format time in this way.
After searching for this, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069411/6536104) and it is about how to use `Timer` function, So I can't log time to log files using it again and again.

**As *W3schools* states,**

> The Timer function returns the number of seconds since 12:00 AM.

But I want my log file to log time in above format even before 12:00 AM, So using `Timer` Function isn't the best option for this.

Please let me know a way to do this specially in log files correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vbscript function `Now()`  will return the current system date and time in this format - `5/2/2017 9:45:34 AM`, however if you need to add milliseconds you can use `Timer` -  [Timer math from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069411/6536104)

```
'capture the date and timer together so if the date changes while 
'the other code runs the values you are using don't change
t = Timer
dateStr = Date()
temp = Int(t)

milliseconds = Int((t-temp) * 1000)

seconds = temp mod 60
temp    = Int(temp/60)
minutes = temp mod 60
hours   = Int(temp/60)
label = "AM"

If hours > 12 Then
    label = "PM"
    hours = hours-12
End If

'format it and add the date
strTime = LeftPad(hours, "0", 2) & ":"
strTime = strTime & LeftPad(minutes, "0", 2) & ":"
strTime = strTime & LeftPad(seconds, "0", 2) & "."
strTime = strTime & LeftPad(milliseconds, "0", 3)


WScript.Echo dateStr & " " & strTime & " " & label

'this function adds characters to a string to meet the desired length
Function LeftPad(str, addThis, howMany)
    LeftPad = String(howMany - Len(str), addThis) & str
End Function
```

Comment: Tell me the purpose of `LeftPad` here.

Comment: Edited  - I wrote the function but didn't implement it - now it is fixed.  LeftPad adds `0`s to the left of the string to make sure it's always the same length.  Without it, 12:09 AM would print as 12:9 AM

Comment: Thanks for that :-)

Comment: I made a small edit to capture the date at the top - it shouldn't normally matter but if your timing is just right it could

Comment: The format `Now()` returns is purely based on the System Regional Settings, it will not always be `5/2/2017 9:45:34 AM` as suggested. End of the day the `Date` and `Time` are stored as a 64-bit signed floating point value representing the number of days that have passed since midnight, December 30, 1899 and the Time portion expresses the current time at a fraction of a day, the format is purely aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing, with a bit less code.  In this code, we're splitting `Now()` into an array so we can use it for everything except the milliseconds.:

```
WScript.Echo PrintTimeStamp()

Function PrintTimeStamp()
    nowParts = SPLIT(Now(), " ")
    timePart = nowParts(1)
    t = Timer
    milliseconds = Int((t-Int(t)) * 1000)
    PrintTimeStamp = nowParts(0) & " " & LeftPad(nowParts(1), "0", 8) & "." & LeftPad(milliseconds, "0", 3) & " " & nowParts(2)
End Function
Function LeftPad(str, addThis, howMany)
    LeftPad = String(howMany - Len(str), addThis) & str
End Function
```

Comment: When I try to use this in a loop like `Do WScript.Echo <DateTime part> Loop`, keeps showing same time agai and again :-|

Comment: I wrapped the time-collecting parts in a function - now you can just call the function inside your loop.